# Is it possible for twitter to view your password?

Tags: twitter, passwords

I've seen multiple "Allow this application to run with twitter" things, but none that have:

- See your twitter password

under "This application will be able to"

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No twitter will never allow people to see your password... they put it just so you are sure that nobody will ever see your password...

They will never share the password. And, the password are surely hashed in the db so they are mostly impossible to decrypt